# Set a store with a function in app.js doesn't work in production build?

Tags: extjs, build, touch, store, production

I'm trying to create a search form view based on the following example of Sencha :
http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/examples/list-search/viewer.html

I made a few changes just not to create the view by code but export it in a view.

To set up the store, i use this in the config :

*store: Preconisations.app.getStoreAdherents(),*

where Preconisations is my project name and getStoreAdherents the function set in the app.js:

```
getStoreAdherents: function () {
    if (!this.storeAdherents) {
        var gestionAdherent = new DAL_Adherent(); // custom classes 
        var tc = gestionAdherent.GetAll(); // and functions which returns a json string with data

        this.storeAdherents = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: "Preconisations.model.ADHERENT",
            data: tc,
            sorters: 'nom',
            groupField: 'code'
        });
    }

    return this.storeAdherents;
}
```

Now, everything works fine but when i make the testing or the production build, i've got this error :

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getStoreAdherents' of undefined**

at the store definition...

Maybe, there's a better way to set up the store by code but i can't understand why it's working in developpement and not with the production or testing build...

Is anyone had this problem ? Or how do you set up dynamically a store with a function ?

Thanks... I'm banging my head on the wall on this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact i think there's a bug in setting a store dynamically in the config.
I found this workaround which work in developpement and in build production :

I don't specify a store : *xxxx* in the view.
Instead, in a controller i put this code in the launch function :

**this.getMainView().setStore(this.getStoreAdherents());**

where getMainView is a reference to my view.

That's all !

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that you have a build dependency issue in Ext Build. In the code snippet posted, there is a chance that you missed to add "Preconisations.model.ADHERENT" to a class path. If so, please add the following to your app.js

`requires: ["Preconisations.model.ADHERENT"]`

If the issue persist, Please do the following diagnostics : 
   Run your app (development mode) in Google Chrome with the Console open; Look for warnings that states a particular class is being synchronously loaded and add requires statement for those classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, i don't think there a problem with my "getStoreAdherents". It seems that the function in the app.js is not initialized when the store config is set. 
There no warning and no error in the Google Chrome console (that the first thing i look at). I notice that when i put a fixed store insted of a functino name, all is good even in build production.

Comment: Hi, I had been to a similar situation recently. What I found is that App.js can fail to initialize in the prod build if you don't have <code>requires: ["Preconisations.model.ADHERENT"]</code>. (There are alternative ways that you can try... ) The model class might not be even loaded if it is not used anywhere else...